# Can't Figure Out how to join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

`SELECT e.ManagerID,  count(*) as NumberOfDepartments
From HumanResources.Employee e, Person.Contact c
where e.ContactID = c.ContactID
group by e.ManagerID;`

The Goal is to write a report to display the managerid, firstname and lastname of that manager and the number of unique different departments they supervise. and only show the manager that supervises the most departments.
I have to ensure that all employees are currently employed (ie enddate does not contain a date).
The code above is working in showing number the managerID and number of department he runs but whenever I try to put in the first name and last name I have to put them also in the 'group by' clause and that way it makes the whole report going crazy. Please Help.
[Database Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6pBa.jpg)

Comment: (a) How can you recognize a manager?

Comment: (b) The manager must be currently occupied, you haven't added this in your query.

Comment: the if there is a value in the managerID it means he/she is a manager

Comment: Probably not; if there is **not** a a value in managerID means they are a manager. This is a tree structure: each employee record points to another Employee record via ManagerID.

Comment: Another question: you get firstname and lastname from `Contact` table, correct? But the relationship between Employee and Contact is one-to-many, or not?

Comment: "it makes the whole report going crazy" - What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

From your schema, seems that the `managerID` column in `Employee` is populated with the ID of the manager for that employee. That would explain why when adding `firstName` and `lastName` the report *goes crazy*, because you'd be grouping by the employee's name, not the manager's.

Without seeing the tables content it's hard to tell, but you may have that managers can be recognised by **not** having `managerID` populated.

If this is the case, you can write your query like this

```
select  e.EmployeeID, c.firstName, e.lastName, count(distinct edh.DepartmentID)
from    Employee e
join    Contact c
on      e.ContactID = c.ContactID
join    Employee e2
on      e1.EmployeeID = e2.ManagerID
join    EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh
on      e2.EmployeeID = edh.EmployeeID 
where   e.ManagerID is null and edh.EndDate is null
group by e.EmployeeID, c.firstName, e.lastName
```

The first instance of `Employee` table is the managers (because you set `where e.ManagerID is null`), the join with `Contact` gets you the managers' names, the second instance of `Employee` gets you all the people managed by each manager, and the join with `EmployeeDepartmentHistory` gets you their department (which you count on) and their `EndDate`, that has to be `null` to ensure you that they're currenty employed.

**Edit**

Please note the way I wrote the joins; writing them as comma separated tables names in your `from` clause with the join condition in your `where` is [a bad habit that should be kicked](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), because it makes reading, maintaining and changing them to outer joins much harder. That's why `join` was introduced in SQL language back in 1992.

Comment: Great work and explanation, Stefano. Still I don't understand the one-to-many relationship between Employee and Contact; shouldn't they share a key?

Comment: Regarding `JOIN`, if they were introduced in 1992 then SQL took too much time to adopt it, it was there in relational algebra from the start (I think). However, I think we exaggerate with the "bad habits to kick": `select * from a, b` is a `CROSS JOIN`, and, though I myself never use it (except in rare situations where I do need a cartesian product), it is still a perfectly legal SQL construct.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis regarding the joins, I edited my answer to be more accurate because you're obviously right, `join` has always been there in relational algebra, and the "bad habit to kick" mostly apply to `inner join`, much less to `cross join`. Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't mean it as a criticism, jut a "kind reminder" that this was not necessarily a habit. Thank you for coming back, take care!

Comment: Thank you for such an amazing explanation, but just to add that even some managers have managers above them and only the CEO doesn't have a manager ID so I think the managerID is null shouldn't be in the code

Comment: Understood, and removing that condition from the `where` clause should work the same (because non managers will be filtered out by the self join). Note that anyways my query will count only the departments a manager directly manages, not the departments managed by "intermediate managers".

Comment: and by the way we've only learned Inner joins and left and right and outer joins (I am a uni student) in the code you only wrote JOIN, what kind of join is that, thanks.

Comment: If you don't specify anything, it's an `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL:

```
SELECT e.ManagerID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDepartments FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN Person.Contact c ON e.ContactID=c.ContactID
GROUP BY e.ManagerID, e.FirstName, e.LastName
```

If you need it in MySql, change ON to WHERE pattern and INNER JOIN to JOIN